# Will styling all the image tags affect google's image ads style?

Tags: html, css, image, ads

I am changing the style of all image tags under a div but google image ads will also be there. Does this changes the style of google image ads?

CSS

```
.articles-container img
{
   height: 400px;
   width: 500px;
   border-radius: 20px;
}
.articles-container img:hover
{
   border: 4px grey solid;
   background: grey;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="articles-container">
   <img src="">
   <img src="">
   <img src="">
   /* want to put google image ads inside */
   <img src="">
   <img src="">
   <img src="">
</div>
```

The css will change img tag style. Hover effect is also there. Will this make any change to google image ads style? Please help me out here. Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0):

Google ads use a different tag to embed the code which should not be affected by this but if there is any img tag present inside , it might get affected. It depends on how you write your CSS.